# Does UDP checksum detect all errors?

Tags: udp, checksum

I just learned about the udp checksum calculation.
But I am confused does the algorithm detect all errors.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. No checksum can detect all errors.

Comment: So do you know why the TCP/IP protocols use this algorithm?

Comment: The IP header also has a checksum. Additionally, most other fields in both the IP and UDP/TCP header have to contain reasonable values for the packet to get accepted. And please don't mix TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 2):

The UDP checksum cannot detect all errors, but it does detect many. It will detect any single bit flip, but if the packet is altered such that the sum of all the data as 16 bit values remains constant, the checksum will not detect the error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually checksums can detect only the most common errors, but not all of them. Actually, the UDP checksum is optional in combination with IPv4 as UDP is designed as an unreliable service.

Answer (score 0):

No, It can not detect all errors.
Suppose we have two 16-bit numbers

```
A = 0101 1001 1010 0010 and
    B = 1010 0100 0110 0101 then Their sum is :
    S = 1111 1110 0000 0111 and 1's(Ones) Complement of this checksum is 
    C = 0000 0001 1111 1000
```

and this checksum will be filled in the checksum      field of UDP Segment.

So Sender will send these 3 16-bit numbers and at receiver sum of A and B will again be calculated at receiver and added to UDP Checksum received .
If we have Sum 1111 1111 1111 1111 then we will think there is no error in recieved segment.
But here is the catch that if
Last two bits in A i.e 10 Get flipped to 01 and similarly
Last two bits in B i.e 01 Get flipped to 10 . Then again S will remain same and S + C will be again 1111 1111 1111 1111. Which is definately a problem as this will not catch error if More than one bit gets flipped.
So, UDP Checksum cannot detect errors of all kinds.